# Why doesn't my array reverse work the way I think it should?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to use the Array.reverse function but it doesn't work. All of the other array functions work for some reason except this one. I've tried writing it in different ways they all don't work.

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  console.log(arr);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].split();
    arr[i] = arr[i].reverse();
  }
  console.log(arr);
  return arr.join(' ');
}
console.log(reverseWords(`Test Input`));
```

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  console.log(arr);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].split('').reverse();
  }
  console.log(arr);
  return arr.join(' ');
}
console.log(reverseWords(`Test Input`));
```

Comment: What does/doesn't it do you think it shouldn't/should? It helps to describe the problem.

Comment: In the bottom one, you need to assign the resulting array. `arr[i] = arr[i].split("").reverse();` In the top one, you need to put an empty string in split(). You probably want `arr[i] = arr[i].split("").reverse().join("")` To turn it back into a string.

Comment: Im trying to reverse the order of letters in each word while still maintaining its position in the sentence.

Comment: You could do it all in one row: `return str.split(' ').map( w => w.split('').reverse().join('') ).join(' ')`

Comment: The error in your first example is that you have no parameter to split (and that you don't join it after the reverse). The error in your second example is that you don't assign the reversed value to anything.

Comment: On a JS programming note, remember that `split` [needs something to split on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), you can't just use `arr[i].split()`: that does nothing (`["abc"].split()` just gives you `["abc"]` back). If you want to turn a string into individual letters, you _have_ to explicitly split on an emptry string: `arr[i].split('');`

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'Input Test' as output:

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  return arr.reverse().join(' ');
}
console.log(reverseWords(`Test Input`));
```

And if you want just reverse letters in the words:

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  return arr.map(x => x.split('').reverse().join(''));
}
console.log(reverseWords(`Test Input`));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using `Array.reverse()` function in a different way than it is expected to be used.

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  console.log(arr);
  arr.reverse();
  console.log(arr);
  return arr.join(' ');
}
console.log(reverseWords(`Test Input`));
```